# Bound on uniform norm of convolution of $L^p$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution

This is Proposition 8.8 in Folland's *Real Analysis*:

> If $p$ and $q$ are conjugate exponents, $f \in L^P$, and $g \in L^q$, then $f*g(x)$ exists for every $x$, $f*g$ is bounded and uniformly continuous, and $\|f*g\|_u \leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q$.
>   If $1 < p < \infty$, then $f*g \in C_0(\mathbb R^n)$.

I have a question about the proof of the estimate
$$
  \|f*g\|_u \leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q .
$$
It says that this estimate follows immediately from Holder's inequality, but it seems to me that Holder would give a bound for $\|f*g\|_1$, not $\|f*g\|_u$.
Am I missing something?

Comment: This is just a special case of Young's inequality.

Comment: @Batman It sure looks like that, until you notice that $p$ and $q$ are assumed to be conjugate, and the word “uniform” in the title. (See the discussion at my answer.)

Comment: The full statement of Young's inequality tells you that $p,q,r$ satisfying $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 + \frac{1}{r}$ and $f \in L^p$, $g \in L^q$, then $||f * g||_r \leq ||f||_p ||g||_q$. in this case, $r = \infty$.

Comment: @Batman Ah, now I see what you mean. OTOH, the “special case” is quite trivial compared to the general case.

Comment: Yep. Though, I realized that Folland uses this case to prove the full case via Riesz-Thorin Interpolation (though he also outlines a proof going around that which is significantly more complicated in the problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition:
$$f*g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)g(x-y)\,dy$$
since $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ (so also $\bigl(y\mapsto g(x-y)\bigr)\in L^q$, with the the same norm as $g$), and Hölder gives you the uniform estimate.

Comment: Don't you need $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=u^{-1}+1$?

Comment: @Taylor From the title of the question, I guessed that $\|\cdot\|_u$ is really the uniform norm, more commonly denoted $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Perhaps I assumed too much; I don't know.

Comment: Thanks. So what I was missing was that $\|f*g\|_u = \|fg\|_1$.

Comment: Oh.  I didn't even know that notation was still used!